# Conversion from excel to .CSV format

Tags: excel-2010, export-to-csv

I have some data in excel format  and it contains Tamil Text as well as English text.
   I am trying to convert the excel sheet into .CSV format after converting English text is coming but Tamil text is Storing like ????? Please help me on this.

Comment: By what programming method do you wish to do this?

Comment: If you look at the tags of the question, it is not a programming problem, in general.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Google Spreadsheet instead of Excel.

Also, the spreadsheet application Calc from OpenOffice is very good at handling CSV data. In the "Save As..." dialog you can click on "Format Options" to get different encodings for CSV. In this way you will be able to save your data correctly.

Excel is not the best tool to handle CSV files.